# How to find two numbers from a std::map whose sum is equal to a target number?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Suppose I've the following map:

```
map<long,int>var;
```

And it contains the following values:

```
var.insert( pair<long, int>(1, 1));
var.insert( pair<long, int>(3, 1));
var.insert( pair<long, int>(5, 1));
var.insert( pair<long, int>(7, 1));
var.insert( pair<long, int>(11, 1));
var.insert( pair<long, int>(20, 1));
```

Now If I pass target value = 10 than I want to print 3, 7 from my map and if target value = 12 than I want to print 5, 7 from my map. I have tried but can't work.
Can anyone please help me, how can I select two numbers from the input map whose sum is equal to a target number.

-- Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to use the map's _keys_? I realize this is most likely a homework, but the requirement to use a map looks weird.

Comment: Why are you using a `map` for this? A map is for *mapping* a key to a value, and all you seem to have is a key, so maybe a `set` would be better? Or even a `vector`?

Comment: What if there are more than 1 such numbers?

Comment: I can do that using vector. But I want to do that using Map/Set.

Comment: @Shimul What do you mean you want to do it using `map`/`set`? Each container has specific purpose. You can't go on substituting one for another in any situation you like!

Comment: @HappyCoder: Suppose I have a set of elements and a target number (probably map is not suitable for this purpose so I may use stl set). Now I want to find two numbers from the stl set, whose sum is equal to the target number. Ex: suppose target number is c, now I want to find a and b from the set so that a + b = c.

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm that finds terms of a target sum:

- Start iterating all the elements with `i`.
- Find the element with key `key = target - i->first`
- If it exists, then print `i->first` and `key` and return.
- Otherwise increment `i`. If `i == end` then there is no answer.

You don't explain how you're using the values of the map. It seems as if you actually want to use a `std::set` instead.

Comment: This algorithm is `O(n log n)` whereas algorithm in `O(n)` exists.

Answer (score 0):

A linear algorithm:

Start from both sides and according to sum, move the correct iterator:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> find_sums(const std::set<int>&s, int total)
{
    if (s.empty()) {
        return {};
    }
    auto b = s.begin();
    auto e = s.end();
    --e;

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> res;
    do {
        auto sum = *b + *e;
        if (sum == total) {
            res.push_back({*b, *e});
            ++b;
        } else if (sum < total) {
            ++b;
        } else { // sum > total
            if (e == s.begin()) {
                break;
            }
            --e;
        }

    } while (b != e);

    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/GgiOsG)